# How to move column data to next row until end starting on specified key

Tags: mysql

I have a table named network_table with this data example:

```
NetworkTableID, MainID, UserID
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 1, 3
4, 1, 4
5, 2, 5
```

So I want to move all the columns data of UserID to the next row starting from NetworkTableID: 2 until the end of the table and there will be another inserted row because the rows moved. I'm expecting a result like this:

```
NetworkTableID, MainID, UserID
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 1, 2
4, 1, 3
5, 2, 4
6, 2, 5
```

This query don't work for me. It gives me a "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'network_table' for update in FROM clause" error.

```
UPDATE network_table
SET UserID = (SELECT UserID FROM network_table as nt2
              WHERE nt2.NetworkTableID=network_table.NetworkTableID-1)
WHERE network_table.NetworkTableID > 2
```

Note: The UserID column is a UNIQUE key.

Comment: Not an answer, but if your desired operation is going from 5 to 6 records, then you're going to have to have an insert in there, probably on top of an update.

Comment: Are you moving then, or just adding 1 to the existing values?

Comment: Im moving the data of the column to the next row starting from a specific networktableid until the end of the row

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the last field if required save a copy:

```
INSERT INTO network_table (MainID,UserID)
SELECT MainID,UserID FROM network_table ORDER BY NetworkTableID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

and then update the table:

```
UPDATE network_table
left join network_table as nt2 on nt2.NetworkTableID=network_table.NetworkTableID-1
SET network_table.UserID =  nt2.UserID
WHERE network_table.NetworkTableID > 2
```